# Pulseaudio 6.0 on raspbian jessi

Tags: audio, bluetooth, pulseaudio

Is there any way to have pulseaudio 6.0 or above working on raspbian system? The thing is that last jessie version comes with pulseaudio 5.0 and this version does not support HSP/HFP bluetooth profiles, so i need a stable version of pulseaudio 6.0 or above to have my bluetooth headset working both speaker and microphone.

Thanks

Comment: May I ask what version is your Raspberry pi? I tried the install from the backports repository and it gives me illegal instruction error, crashed at libpulsecommon.so library. I am using raspberry pi version 1 model B

Comment: Yes it is and I’ve used it in a few rpi projects. Take a look here near the bottom of the script it compiles pa6 and sets a few services. But if you just want pa6 it should be apparent what is needed from the script.    https://github.com/BaReinhard/Super-Simple-Raspberry-Pi-Audio-Receiver-Install/blob/master/bt_pa_config.sh#L150

Answer (score 1):

I got pulseaudio 7 running on my raspberry jessie. I used this post, in DEBIAN, if it can be useful (but remember: IN DEBIAN). Debian 8 Jessie.

> I've found a way to use pc like an headset with Android phone (for making callings).
>       !!! I've use pulseaudio from jessie-backports: I don't know how much this takes risks ;-) !!!

In /etc/apt/sources.list add:

```
deb http://ftp.jp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.jp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

Then:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install pulseaudio=7.1-2~bpo8+1 pulseaudio-utils=7.1-2~bpo8+1 \
    pulseaudio-module-x11=7.1-2~bpo8+1 pulseaudio-module-bluetooth=7.1-2~bpo8+1 \
    libpulse-mainloop-glib0=7.1-2~bpo8+1 libpulsedsp=7.1-2~bpo8+1 libpulse0=7.1-2~bpo8+1 \
    libpulse0:i386=7.1-2~bpo8+1
```

Create a file (with same ownership of /var/lib/gdm3) (create directories if necessary)

```
/var/lib/gdm3/.config/pulse/client.conf
autospawn = no
daemon-binary = /bin/true
[http://www.gem.mydns.jp/daitei/linux/jessie/bt-headset/]
```

Install "ofono"in /etc/pulse/default.pa modify the line:

```
load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

to:

```
load-module module-bluetooth-discover headset=auto
```

Restart pulseaudio:

```
killall -9 pulseaudio
```

It is not necessary to "pulseaudio --start" because from pulseaudio 6 it will restart automatically.

About parameters of "load-module module-bluetooth-discover":

```
headset=native -> only a2dp
headset=ofono -> only headset
headset=auto -> a2dp and headset !!!
```

Check this command:

```
pactl list cards
```

I couldnt try the HSP profile but i will next week i guess. i think hfp works but for my purpose its useless because you cant connect a Headset to the Pi.

Comment: The question is how to send/receive audio from headset-like device to RPI as a host

Comment: if you get unable to locate package libpulse0, there is a suggestion to do: apt-get -t jessie-backports install pulseaudio